# Корректно ли выражение "апофеоз кульминаций"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Имеет ли право на существование выражение "апофеоз кульминаций"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Апофеоз — заключительная торжественная массовая сцена музыкального или драматического спектакля, праздничной концертной программы, циркового представления, прославляющая народ, героя, какое-либо событие и т. п. Апофеоз носит обычно монументальный характер и исполнен особого подъёма, величия. 
Классический пример апофеоза — заключительная сцена в опере «Иван Сусанин» Глинки. Апофеоз может являться также самостоятельной частью (обычно без текста) какого-либо представления, празднества, шествия и т. п. Такие апофеозы строятся на выразительных группировках и позах действующих лиц (эффектная "живая картина", пластически выражающая основную идею зрелища, «немая сцена»), в них используются яркое декорационное оформление, костюмы (от латинского *costume*).

Таким образом, апофеоз — это кульминация, наивысший момент какого-либо действия, сцены. Апофеоз, будучи финальной, высшей стадией чего-либо (например, концертного выступления), всегда выступает развязкой, завершающим моментом. Апофеоз характеризуется торжественностью момента, наибольшей значимостью по сравнению с предыдущими действиями. Апофеоз — это венец всех предшествующих событий.

**Получается, что фраза носит избыточный, тавтологический  характер, следовательно, некорректна.**

Answer (score 1):

Апофеоз, если игнорировать театральные и литературные значения, — это развязка или кульминация. "Кульминация кульминаций" право на существование, конечно, имеет, но разве что иронично, а назвать его корректным как-то язык не поворачивается.

Апофеоз: в театральном жаргоне — заключительная массовка, в литературном языке — вознесение древнегреческих героев и римских императоров к статусу божеств (очень примерный перевод).

Comment: Апофеоз, кроме описанного вами, значит "прославление, возвеличение какого-л. лица, явления, события и т. п.".

Answer (score -1):

1) **А давайте-ка возьмем словарь, что он нам скажет:**

**АПОФЕОЗ**,  [греч. apothéōsis — обожествление]. 1. В Древней Греции и Риме: обряд **обожествления какого-л. героя, императора** и т.п. 2. чего, чему. **Прославление, возвеличение какого-л. лица, явления, события** и т.п. "Римские элегии" Гёте — а. древней жизни. Птичий хор — а. природе и солнцу. 3. **Заключительная торжественная массовая сцена** спектакля или праздничной концертной программы. Опера в пяти актах с апофеозом.

Интересно то, что я **не вижу здесь слов "кульминация" или "развязка"**, и думается мне, что апофеозная сцена — **это особый элемент** театральной постановки. И  заметьте — это **только третье** значение слова в словаре.

Дело в том, что  живем мы не Древнем Риме, оперы в пяти актах с апофеозом в конце  тоже посещаем не часто, и поэтому нам больше подходит **второе значение слова: прославление, возвеличивание чего-либо,  а иногда, напротив, осуждение (в случае иронического употребления слова)**. Именно в этом значении пользователи русского языка чаще всего используют слово "апофеоз".

В качестве справки: **Кульминация** — точка, момент наивысшего напряжения в **развитии** чего-л.  **Развязка** (лит.) —  эпизод, заключающий, завершающий развитие сюжета художественного произведения. (противоп.: завязка).

**Так можно ли считать правильными ответы, в которых говорится следующее:** Таким образом, апофеоз — это кульминация, наивысший момент какого-либо действия, сцены. **Это ли качественная информация, которую мы представляем посетителям сайта?**

2) **Ответ на вопрос (тот, который не является полезным)**

В Нацкорпусе  "апофеоз" встречается часто (385 примеров), причем в большинстве случаев его употребление не связано со сценой,  **Апофеозом называют всё,** например: Смотрела на дорогу: её покрасили, как на этой картинке. Это апофеоз! День поэзии» в новом огромном книжном магазине: апофеоз!

Таким образом, апофеоз превратился в наивысшее торжество проявления любых сторон общественной или личной жизни.

**Выражение "апофеоз кульминаций" имеет не очень ясный смысл** (надо смотреть текст), но можно предположить, что это просто **восторженная оценка кульминации какого-либо спектакля, романа**, то есть  уже не тавтология, а всё тот же переносный смысл в восприятии любого предмета, в том числе и кульминационной сцены спектакля.